# Binding a DateTime to a date input field with Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

What's the best way to do that?

When i bind the **value** of the *input* element to my **DateTime** instance, a *String* is returned:

```html
<input value="{{myDate}}" type="date">
```

Is there a specific attribute to bind the input to a DateTime instance?

Or should i use a filter?

[EDIT]

here is my working filter (only works with "date" input type):
https://gist.github.com/Vloz/10553552

Comment: an approach similar the the one shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314709 should work

Answer (score 0):

`input` elements don't provide an attribute that provides the typed value of the input. You'll need to provide a custom handler that parses the `String` value and updates your element's `DateTime` typed attribute.

e.g.

```
<input type="date" value="{{dateString}}">

...

// inside the element's script...

date: null,  // the DateTime typed attribute

// this handler automatically works
dateStringChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    this.date = DateTime.parse(newValue);  // how about some error handling too?
},
```