# Polymer dart: Data bind integer value to String attribute

Tags: data-binding, binding, filter, dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to bind an integer to a String attribute. To say exactly, I am trying to bind a published integer variable to the value attribute of the text input element.

@published int data = 0;

```dart
<input type="number" value="{{data}}">
```

Obviously, a reference of String is getting stored in what is supposed to be an integer.

I tried to use filter to solve this issue, but still could get it to work:

```dart
int integerize(Object a) {
  int ret = 0;
  if (a is String) {
    try {
      ret = int.parse(a);
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
    }
  } else if( a is int) {
    ret = a;
  }
  return ret;
}

<input type="number" value="{{data | integerize}}">
```

So I switched to not using binding for this. Can somebody suggest a better, efficient solution using binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Polymer 1.0.0** this worked fine for me

Create a reusable behavior or just add the `convertToNumeric()` to your Polymer element:

```
@HtmlImport('app_element.html')
library app_element;
import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@behavior
abstract class InputConverterBehavior implements PolymerBase {
  @reflectable
  void convertToInt(dom.Event e, _) {
    final input = (e.target as dom.NumberInputElement);
    double value = input.valueAsNumber;
    int intValue =
        value == value.isInfinite || value.isNaN ? null : value.toInt();
    notifyPath(input.attributes['notify-path'], intValue);
  }
}
```

Apply the behavior to your element:

```
@PolymerRegister('app-element')
class AppElement extends PolymerElement with InputConverterBehavior {
  AppElement.created() : super.created();

  @property int intValue;
}
```

In HTML of your element configure the input element:

- bind `value` to your property: `value="[[intValue]]"` so the input element gets updated when the property changes
- set up event notification to call the converter when the value changes `on-input="convertToNumeric" notify-path="intValue"` where `intValue` is the name of the property to update with the numeric value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<dom-module id='app-element'>
  <template>
    <style>
      input:invalid {
        border: 3px solid red;
      }
    </style>
    <input type="number" value="[[intValue]]"
           on-input="convertToInt" notify-path="intValue">

    <!-- a 2nd element just to demonstrate that 2-way-binding -->
    <input type="number" value="[[intValue]]"
           on-input="convertToInt" notify-path="intValue">
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

---

**An alternative approach**

Create a property as getter/setter:

```
  int _intValue;
  @property int get intValue => _intValue;
  @reflectable set intValue(value) => convertToInt(value, 'intValue');
```

Create a behavior or add the function directly to your element

```
@behavior
abstract class InputConverterBehavior implements PolymerBase {
  void convertToInt(value, String propertyPath) {
    int result;
    if (value == null) {
      result = null;
    } else if (value is String) {
      double doubleValue = double.parse(value, (_) => double.NAN);
      result =
          doubleValue == doubleValue.isNaN ? null : doubleValue.toInt();
    } else if (value is int) {
      result = value;
    } else if (value is double) {
      result =
          value == value.isInfinite || value.isNaN ? null : value.toInt();
    }
    set(propertyPath, result);
  }
}
```

This way you can use the same markup as for text input fields

```
<input type="number" value="{{intValue::input}}">
```

or if you want to delay the update of the property until the input field is left

```
<input type="number" value="{{intValue::change}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for **Polymer <= 0.16**. For **Polymer >= 1.0** see my other answer.

HTML attributes store only string values. What you could do is to use a getter/setter for binding and parse when the value is set.

```dart
@observable
int data;

@ComputedProperty('data') // haven't tried this but should work - see comments on http://japhr.blogspot.co.at/2014/08/whats-difference-between-attribute-and.html
@observable
get dataValue => data;
set dataValue(val) {
  if(val == null) {
    data = 0;
  } else if(val is num) {
    data = val.toInt();
  } else if(val is String) {
    data = num.parse(val, (v) => 0).toInt();
  } else {
    data = 0;
  }
}
```

or use a transformer or custom Polymer expressions
like explained in [polymer dart input binding int properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314709)

**Alternative approache**
uses Dart Polymer 1.0 (also possible with Dart Polymer 0.16)

**app_element.dart**

```dart
@HtmlImport('app_element.html')
library _template.web.app_element;

import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@PolymerRegister('app-element')
class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
  AppElement.created() : super.created();

  @property int intValue;
  @property String stringValue;

  @reflectable
  valueInputHandler(dom.Event event, [_]) {
    var input = (event.target as dom.NumberInputElement);
    var value = input.valueAsNumber;
    if (!value.isNaN && !value.isInfinite) {
      set('intValue', value.toInt());
      input.setCustomValidity('');
    } else {
      // just to get the `:invalid` pseudo-class for styling
      input.setCustomValidity('Not a number.');
    }
  }
}
```

**app_element.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<dom-module id='app-element'>
  <template>
    <style>
      input:invalid {
        border: 3px solid red;
      }
    </style>
    <input type="number"
           value="{{stringValue::input}}"
           on-input="valueInputHandler" >
    <div>stringValue: <span>{{stringValue}}</span></div>
    <div>intValue:<span>{{intValue}}</span></div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```