# How to catch data type mismatch exception in PolymerElement?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I created a custom tag x-account with a attribute balance which is double type. This exception throw when user input non numeric data to amount.

Uncaught Error: Error evaluating expression 'balance': type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double' of 'value'.

```
@CustomTag('x-account')
class XAccount extends PolymerElement {
     @published double balance;
     ...
}

<template>
    <input id="account-amount" type="number" value="{{balance}}" autocomplete="off"/>
</template>
```

How to catch this exception inside XAccount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your field to a getter/setter

```dart
double _balance;
@published 
double get balance => _balance;
set balance(value) {
  if(value == null) {
    _balance = null; // or _balance = 0;
  }
  if(value is String) {
    _balance = double.parse(value)
  }
}
```

This way you can wrap assignments or statements which might throw in a `try`/`catch` block.

For Polymer 1.0 see [Polymer dart: Data bind integer value to String attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611667/polymer-dart-data-bind-integer-value-to-string-attribute/33076868#33076868)